# Does Trello maintain a list of "Favorite" boards?

Tags: trello

I view a handful of Trello boards daily. Some, I own and show up on my "Boards" button. I'd like to add other boards (that I do not own) to this list for quick linking; a list of "Favorites," if you will.

I could not find this feature after a brief tour of the guide.

Does this feature exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trello doesn't have "Favorites" exactly, but you can control which boards show up in your boards menu by "pinning" (or "unpinning") a board

If there is a board that you aren't a member of, but you'd like to keep an eye on (e.g. the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)), you can add it to your **Boards Menu**

1. Click the icon next to the board title (or click the **Board Profile** button on the right)
2. Click **"Pin to Header Menu"**

[image: The "Pin to Header Menu" menu item]

(The Boards Menu is the list of boards you see when you click the "Boards" link in the upper right)

You can also use that menu to unpin boards that you don't want in your header.  (e.g. if you're a member of a board, but you don't check it very frequently)

A list of all of your boards, including the ones that are not pinned, is available on [**your boards page**](https://trello.com/your/boards)

Comment: Ah, "pin" is what I was after. I did not correlate this to what I called "favorite," but I see it now. I'm so used to what it means in my IDE that I glossed over any other interpretation. Thank you.